# AlarmManager don't run as expectly

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

As you suggested me to use AlarmManager instead of Timer, I thought, the program will run.
But unfortunately, it does not. Or, better, not always...

This is my code:

```
long millis = 0;

this.alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.main.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

this.checkPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.main, 0,
              new Intent(this.main, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);

if(frequency.compareTo("1HOUR") == 0)
  millis = 3600 * 1000;
if(frequency.compareTo("12HOUR") == 0)
  millis = 12 * 3600 * 1000;
if(frequency.compareTo("1DAY") == 0)
  millis = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
if(frequency.compareTo("1WEEK") == 0)
  millis = 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;

this.alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        System.currentTimeMillis(), millis, this.checkPendingIntent);
```

I'm expecting that the pending intent (AlarmReceiver) will be called every X milliseconds, but it does not.
I can see in the logs of my phone, that it will not be called, and in the log of my server (the receiver sends an HTTP-Request), that no requests are received.

VERY strange is, that sometime it runs, but I can't reproduce the situation.

Can someone say me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot
Luca Bertoncello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example of how to use the Alarm

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, yourHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, yourMin);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, youSec);

if (calendar.before(now)) { //if time passed
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
}
Intent intent = new Intent(Context.this, DestinationActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
               (Settings.this,123456, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

Use setRepeating if you want your alarm to be Repeated daily.
If you don`t want use setAlarm(..,..,..,..) instead

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Could you just explain me why you use setTimeInMillis for the calendar and then again calendar.set?

Comment: Well, it seems to work... I'll test your example today and tomorrow, expecting a request every hour. Thanks a lot

Comment: @LucaBertoncello You can set the alarm then change the time from setting. When the time of the alarm come, the Alarm will be fired..Please if you find my answer useful, vote it UP and accept it as your answer

Comment: Hi. After some tests, I can say, that you solutions works! Unfortunately, I can't vote. But now I have another problem: if the device will be restarted, the Alarm will NOT work anymore, until I start it again... How can I fix this problem?

Comment: OK, I found the solution! I have to create a BroadcastReceiver for BOOT_COMPLETED...

Comment: @LucaBertoncello  yes, the solution will be by giving the Permission in the Mainafist to run Reciever on Boot, then declair a class from Type Receiver and put your action in the onRecieve method :)

Answer (score 0):

check out this-

```
Intent intentalarm = new Intent("com.mubble.powercutsensorapp.MYTIMER");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentalarm, 0);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long interval = 24*60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 hour
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now + interval, interval,
        pendingIntent);
```